# Play a video whose URL is not known in advance - without reload - without extra tab

Tags: iphone, video, safari, mobile-safari

I have lots of buttons on a web page. Depending on which one is clicked, I want to play a different video.

A large number of `<video>` elements doesn't seem to work particularly quickly or reliably.

So far, I have tried to:

1. Create and play() the video element dynamically, after an image is clicked:

   ```
   var video = document.createElement('video');
   video.src = 'video.mp4';
   document.body.appendChild(video.play);
   video.play();
   ```

   This works on iOS 4, but not on iOS 3.
2. Create the video element before, and just change the `src`.

   Doesn't work either.

   It seems like the video object must have already done "it's thing", before it can be played.
3. Use `window.open()` to open the video URL.

   This will cause an annoying new tab to open, which will remain open after playback has completed.
4. Set `window.location`

   This will cause the current page to be reloaded after playback has completed, which I'm trying to avoid.

Any more ideas?